Should Conference Paper Reviewers Conduct Preliminary Literature Searches Before Evaluating Submissions?
I am curious about the extent to which reviewers should engage with the existing literature before evaluating a submitted paper.
Specifically, is it advisable or expected for reviewers to search for related papers and examine the cited references within the submission before forming their assessment?

One hope that reviewers selected for conferences are already engaged with the literature.

Literature search should be done by the author before submission...

of course they should, the bigger question is rather: do they?

This has something to do with the deadline given to the reviewer. Sometimes reviewers are asked to submit a review in a week or so, and of course everybody knows they have other stuff to do, so the editor (or generally the person who asked you to review) may know they can not realistically expect that.

I don't know of any statistics on this, and it almost certainly varies by field, conference, and even reviewer.
But a good reviewer for a conference presentation will be a lot like a good reviewer for a paper. They should already be fairly familiar with the field, they should check the recent literature, and so on.
But the standards for some conferences will be different than for some journals. Some conferences welcome work that is less polished than would be right for a journal. This could be purely practical (there are some conferences that have trouble getting enough submissions, especially with shrinking budgets for conference attendance), it could be a way to encourage students to present, or it could be a way to get the latest stuff, before it is "finished".
The author of the presentation should still do their job, but ... it pays to check.

In theory, I don't think there is much difference between a conference review and a paper review. In practice, at least in my fields (business management and computer science), conference articles tend to be shorter and the deadlines tend to be much tighter. So, the main difference is that reviewers tend to spend less time on them and write shorter reviews.
So, I will answer for both journal and conference papers. A reviewer who wants to write a good-quality review might very well read some related articles and do some literature searches as part of their peer-review process. This depends both on how familiar the reviewer is with the topic and on how much time they are willing to spend. (Even if the reviewer is an expert, it is unlikely they are an expert on every major aspect of the article. They might be an expert on the theory but not on the methodology, or vice versa, so might want to read up on the aspects they are weaker.)
Coming back to my original point on the difference between conference and journal article reviews, it ultimately depends on how much time a reviewer is willing to spend on an article. The more expert and experienced a reviewer is on the topic, the less they will need to look up supplementary materials, but the less time they are willing or able to spend on the review, the less time they will look up supplementary materials, even if it would have helped the quality of their review.
So, ultimately, it depends on how high quality a review a reviewer is willing to submit. If reading references would help increase the quality and the reviewer is willing to spend the time to do so, then they may. If they are not willing to spend that extra time or do not feel they need to do so to write a high-quality review, then they won't. It is hard to expect more than that of a volunteer.
